# How to unthread?

Tags: expression-manipulation

For example

```
{a + b} == {c + d} // Thread
(*{a + b == c + d}*)
```

how to get `{a + b} == {c + d}` from `{a + b == c + d}` ?

This is my try

```
Equal @@ List /@ Join @@ {a + b == c + d}
```

Are there other ways to do this?

Comment: `Map[List, {a + b == c + d}, {2}]`

Comment: `{a + b == c + d} /. f_[x_, y_] :> f[{x}, {y}]` (only in special cases)

Comment: Just for fun: `Equal @@ Tuples@{a + b == c + d}` => {a + b} == {c + d}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be

```
Distribute[{a + b == c + d}, Equal]
```

Same as

```
Thread[{a + b == c + d}, Equal]
```

More universal

```
{a + b == c + d}/. f_[g_[x_, y_]] -> g[f[x], f[y]]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm completely a mess on these. How do you change {a==b,c==d} to {a+c==b+d} again using Thread?

Comment: @xslittlegrass, If you really need Thread for this, maybe: `{Thread[Total@{a == b, c == d}, Equal]}`, another way would be: `Inner[Plus, Sequence @@ {a == b, c == d}, Equal]`

Comment: (+1) I like the `Thread` way.  It seems more natural in this case, where threading is basically transposition with different heads.  In fact, it seems more universal than the replacement rule, certainly with respect to number of arguments, but also considering that one specifies the head for `Thread` in the first place, either `List` by default or explicitly by it optional second argument.

Answer (score 1):

The `Thread` operation is not completely invertible in all cases, but if we assume that

- only level 1 is to be considered, and
- in the original `Thread`, all arguments had the same head and length,

then the expression can be unthreaded.  Perhaps others can extend this.

Here, in `unthread[expr, h]`, if `expr` is of the form

```
f[h[a1, a2,...], h[b1, b2,...],...]
```

the the result will be

```
h[f[a1, b1,...], f[a1, b2,...],...]
```

The default for `h` is `List`.  Thus `unthread[f[h[a1, a2,...],..., h]` undoes `Thread[h[f[a1, b1,...],...], f]`.

```
Clear[unthread];
unthread::usage = "unthread[f[args], h]  \"unthreads\"  f  over  args  each with head  h";
unthread::tdlen = "Objects of unequal length in `` cannot be uncombined. :)";
unthread::head = "Objects in `` not all of type ``.";
unthread[expr_, h_: List] /;
     (Length@DeleteDuplicates[Length /@ expr] == 1 ||
       (Message[unthread::tdlen, expr]; False)) &&
     (DeleteDuplicates[Head /@ List @@ expr] == {h} ||
       (Message[unthread::head, expr, h]; False)) := 
  With[{h2 = Head[expr]}, h @@ h2 @@@ Transpose[List @@ List @@@ expr]];
unthread[expr_, h_] := expr;  (* return expressions that do not satisfy criteria *)
```

Examples

```
unthread[{a + b == c + d}, Equal]
(* {a + b} == {c + d} *)

unthread[g[f[a, aa], f[b, bb], f[c, cc]], f]
(* f[g[a, b, c], g[aa, bb, cc]] *)

unthread[g[f[a, aa], f[b, bb], f[c, cc, ccc]], f]
(* unthread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in g[f[a,aa], f[b,bb], f[c,cc,ccc]]
    cannot be uncombined. :) *)
(* g[f[a, aa], f[b, bb], f[c, cc, ccc]] *)

unthread[g[f[a, aa], f[b, bb], h[c, cc]], f]
(* unthread::head: Objects in g[f[a,aa], f[b,bb], h[c,cc]] not all of type f. *)
(* g[f[a, aa], f[b, bb], h[c, cc]] *)
```

An example in which two different `Thread` operations yield the same output, which shows `Thread` is not completely reversible.

```
Thread[f[g[a, b, c], g[aa, bb, cc], d], g]
(* g[f[a, aa, d], f[b, bb, d], f[c, cc, d]] *)

Thread[f[g[a, b, c], g[aa, bb, cc], g[d, d, d]], g]
(* g[f[a, aa, d], f[b, bb, d], f[c, cc, d]] *)
```